# Delete all the entries but the specified Key set from Hash Map

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I am trying to delete all the entries in HashMap apart from the specified Set of Keys.
For example say HashMap numToalphaMap has entries 1-->a, 2-->b, 3-->c, 4-->d. Given KeySet is {1, 2}. I want to delete other entries ie.., (3-->c, 4-->d) from the numToalphaMap. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way (in Java 8) is to just delete any keys not in `keySet`:

```
map.keySet().removeIf(k -> !keySet.contains(k));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java 8, how about the below stream solution?

```
    Set<Integer> keysToKeep = new HashSet<>();
    keysToKeep.add(1);
    keysToKeep.add(2);

    Map<Integer, String> intToStringMap = new HashMap<>();
    intToStringMap.put(1, "a");
    intToStringMap.put(2, "b");
    intToStringMap.put(3, "c");
    intToStringMap.put(4, "d");


    Map<Integer, String> filteredMap = 
            intToStringMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(x -> keysToKeep.contains(x.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Java 7 version:

```
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entryIterator = intToStringMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while (entryIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = entryIterator.next();
        if(!keysToKeep.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            entryIterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. But the problem is my compiler is 1.7 and i am not allowed to update it to 1.8. So how can i do the similar thing on 1.7?

Comment: You can use the entrySet's iterator and remove it in place. Note that you have to use an iterator otherwise you will get a ConcurrentModificationException if you try to remove an element from a collection you are currently iterating over.  Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For performance consideration, you can first determine if the key set you can to keep is large or small. If only it's small you can create a new HashMap and assign the key-value pair in that new one. Otherwise, you can iterate and remove those aren't in the set as following:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   if (keySet.contains(entry.getKey())) {
     entry.remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: You will get a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException if you try to run this. You cannot modify a collection will you are iterating over it without using an Iterator.

Comment: for (var it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
      var entry = it.next();
      if (keySet.contains(entry.getKey())) {
        it.remove();
      }
    }